# LD is producing 2000 lines of assembly for a 3 line C file. How can I get it to only produce the assembly needed?

Tags: c, macos, assembly, disassembly

I'm currently working through a document titled "Building a Simple OS -- from scratch". It teaches x86 instructions only in 32-bit. At one point the author lists this C function:

```
int my_function() {
  return 0xbaba;
}
```

and says that it compiles into this assembly:

```
00000000  55                push ebp
00000001  89E5              mov ebp, esp 
00000003  B8BABA0000        mov eax, 0xbaba 
00000008  5D                pop ebp
00000009  C3                ret
```

I have the code for `my_function()` in a file called `basic.c` and I'm using the following bash instructions (on Mac OS X Yosemite w/ Xcode installed):

```
gcc -ffreestanding -m32 -c basic.c -o basic.o
ld -arch i386 -no_pie -e _my_function -static -o basic.bin -image_base 0x0 basic.o
```

These are successful, but when I run

```
ndisasm -b 32 basic.bin > basic.dis
```

I get a file with over 2000 lines of assembly, most of which are

```
00000FDA  0000              add [eax],al
```

How can I get it to just compile to the simple five lines listed by author?

Comment: What does the map file say that the segment with all the nulls is?

Comment: I think you want the output of the compiler, so check `basic.o` instead of `basic.bin`. `ld` links all the object files together.

Comment: Something like `gcc ... -S basic.c` should give you an assembly listing, `basic.s` for just that function. The `basic.bin` file (presumably an executable) will contain a lot of boilerplate code needed to run a complete program.

Comment: Did you perchance get an ELF binary instead of what you wanted?

Comment: Maybe it is just me but I felt this question (minus the irrelevant tag) was reasonable. I'd be curious what the downvoters would prefer to see.

Comment: Are you sure that you're getting a binary file as output from `ld`? When I build raw binaries I usually have an `objcopy -O binary foo.elf foo.bin` as my final build step (where `foo.elf` is the output from `ld`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be looking at the `.o` file, not the linked file (or using a different tool to disassemble just the desired function in the linked file). Per the [manual](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoca.html):

> NDISASM does not have any understanding of object file formats, like objdump, and it will not understand DOS .EXE files like debug will. It just disassembles.

`ld` in the OS X / Xcode toolchain produces a Mach-O binary. This includes various metadata in addition to the machine code for the function. `ndisasm` isn't aware of the file structure and is attempting to disassemble the metadata as code (which it isn't).